# Qt: How to use an accesspoint throughout the application?

Tags: qt, nokia, qt-mobility, access-point

I'm developing an application for Symbian S60 phones using the Qt Nokia SDK, which sends requests and receives responses from a webservice in every view i have.

The problem with this, is that it always asks the user to choose a accesspoint.

So what i want is to choose an accesspoint when the application starts, and use that throughout the application.

So i found this example: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_set_default_access_point_using_Qt_Mobility_APIs

but i got following error:

> undefined reference to 'QtMobility::QNetworkConfigurationManager::QNetworkConfigurationManager(QObject*)

i'm also getting more of these errors from other classes from QMobillity, like:

> undefined reference to 'QtMobility::QNetworkSession::open()

.pro file:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += bearer
```

header:

```
#include <qmobilityglobal.h>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QNetworkSession>
#include <QNetworkConfigurationManager>

QTM_USE_NAMESPACE;
```

cpp file:

```
        QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;
        const bool selectIap = (manager.capabilities()& QNetworkConfigurationManager::CanStartAndStopInterfaces);
        QNetworkConfiguration defaultIap = manager.defaultConfiguration();

        if(!defaultIap.isValid() && (!selectIap && defaultIap.state() != QNetworkConfiguration::Active))
        {
            qDebug() << "Network access point NOT found";

            // let the user know that there is no access point available
            msgBox->setText(tr("Error"));
            msgBox->setInformativeText(tr("No default access point available"));
            msgBox->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
            msgBox->setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
            msgBox->topLevelWidget();
            msgBox->exec();
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Network access point found and chosen";
        }

        session = new QNetworkSession(defaultIap,this);
        session->open();
```

Anyone got an idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to the .PRO file?

```
CONFIG += network
```